# My calculator app crashes when I click the equal button several times, how to resolve this problem?

Tags: android, calculator

How to prevent the app from crashing due to clicking the button several times.

Here's the code:

```
equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                compute();
                ACTION = EQU;
                result.setText(result.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(val2) + "=" + String.valueOf(val1));
                // 5 + 4 = 9
                info.setText(null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please share a stack trace.

Comment: Remember share a stack trace to get a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Hello you have just to delete info.settext("null")

```
equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                compute();
                ACTION = EQU;
                result.setText(result.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(val2) + "=" + String.valueOf(val1));
                // 5 + 4 = 9
                info.setText("");
            }
        }
```

);

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved my problem by putting if statement first

```
equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (info.getText().length() != 0) { 
                compute();
                ACTION = EQU;
                result.setText(result.getText().toString() + String.valueOf(val2) + "=" + String.valueOf(val1));
                // 5 + 4 = 9
                info.setText(null);
            }}
        });
```